# Google Maps not rendering at all

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've worked previously with maps and I've never faced an issue where the map doesn't render at all.

Here's fiddle with my code implementation including a request to the places API library

http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/Ljn1n6nh/

Here's my code sample:

JS:

```
function initialize() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('map-dire');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(elem, {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

It's the simplest form of maps but it's always rendering a grey/beige box and if I click anywhere it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`. I understand this error shows when the DOM element for the map isn't loaded. But doesn't the map trigger only when the `window` element is loaded?

Comment: You are not setting latitute and longitude for Map

Comment: @VivekGupta I don't think thats the issue. Either way, here's an updated fiddle with lat and long http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/Ljn1n6nh/1/

Comment: adding latitude and longitude in my answer plz see it is showing map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
**center and zoom are Required.**
```

Try to send latitude and longitude dynamically, I am giving hard coded values for reference

```
function initialize() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('map-dire');
   var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(elem, mapOptions);
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

Your edited jsfiddle is also working if you give zoom property like

```
function initialize() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('map-dire');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(elem, {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},zoom: 8
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

Comment: I guess the issue is ignoring Zoom option

Comment: It does seem like not having the zoom option was the issue. The moment I plugged it in, everything was working. Thanks! Was beating my head over this

Answer (score 0):

There are two **required** (mandatory) [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

- **center**    LatLng  The initial Map center. **Required**.
- **zoom**      number  The initial Map zoom level. **Required**.

If you don't provide them you must call map.setCenter() and map.setZoom(), map.fitBounds() [which computes both], use a KmlLayer with preserveViewport set to false [which also computes both] or some other operation which results in them both being set (so the map will be initialized).

**code snippet which calls map.setCenter() and map.setZoom():**

```js
function initialize() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('map-dire');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(elem, {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  });
  map.setCenter({lat: 0,lng: 0});
  map.setZoom(2);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

```css
#map-dire {
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="search-box">
        <input id="search-places" class="jr-input" focusdir search-box placeholder="Enter location">
        <div id="directions-panel" class="directions-panel">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div id="map-dire">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**code snippet that sets `center` and `zoom`:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('map-dire');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(elem, {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: {lat: 0,lng: 0},
    zoom: 2
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

```css
#map-dire {
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="search-box">
        <input id="search-places" class="jr-input" focusdir search-box placeholder="Enter location">
        <div id="directions-panel" class="directions-panel">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div id="map-dire">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```